# Guideline on setting hyphenation preferences in German compounds

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, german, discretionary

Let's say we wish to provide different priorities of hyphenation points in long compound words in German.  Here is what we tried out for now:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}
\ifluatex
  %\hyphenpenalty is 50 by default
  \exceptionpenalty=51%%% ad-hoc value greater than \hyphenpenalty.
  \exhyphenpenalty=46%%% an ad-hoc value less than \hyphenpenalty (though usually they coincide). We choose the value such that it's one less than the minimum over the hyphenation penalties of the explicitly specified compounds.
  % \babelhyphenation[ngerman]{
  %   In{-}{}{}[3]ter{-}{}{}[1]ak{-}{}{}[2]ti{-}{}{}[4]ons-dia{-}{}{}[2]gram{-}{}{}[3]me
  %   In{-}{}{}[3]ter{-}{}{}[1]ak{-}{}{}[2]ti{-}{}{}[4]ons-ver{-}{}{}[1]fei{-}{}{}[3]ne{-}{}{}[3]rung
  %   In{-}{}{}[4]ter{-}{}{}[2]ak{-}{}{}[3]ti{-}{}{}[5]ons{-}{}{}[1]ver{-}{}{}[2]fei{-}{}{}[4]ne{-}{}{}[4]rungs-dia{-}{}{}[3]gramm
  % }%%% this way we get too large penalties.  Breaking the words specified this way is discouraged (and thus, breaking the unspecified words is implicitly encouraged).
  \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{In|ter|ak|ti|ons|dia|gram|me}%% set potentially different preferences of the hyphenation points in “Interaktionsdiagramme”
  {
    {}, {},         % In
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=2},
    {}, {}, {},     % ter
    {pre=-, penalty=49, data=6},
    {}, {},         % ak
    {pre=-, penalty=50, data=9},
    {}, {},         % ti
    {pre=-, penalty=52, data=12}, %%% higher penalty because of the pronunciation t͡si̯oː
    {}, {}, {},     % ons
    {pre=-, penalty=48, data=16},
    {}, {}, {},     % dia
    {pre=-, penalty=50, data=20},
    {}, {}, {}, {}, % gram
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=25},
    {}, {}          % me
  }% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is ≈ 50.14.
  \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{In|ter|ak|ti|ons|ver|fei|ne|rung}%% set potentially different preferences of the hyphenation points in “Interaktionsverfeinerung”
  {
    {}, {},        % In
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=2},
    {}, {}, {},    % ter
    {pre=-, penalty=49, data=6},
    {}, {},        % ak
    {pre=-, penalty=50, data=9},
    {}, {},        % ti
    {pre=-, penalty=52, data=12}, %%% higher penalty because of the pronunciation t͡si̯oː
    {}, {}, {},    % ons
    {pre=-, penalty=48, data=16},
    {}, {}, {},    % ver
    {pre=-, penalty=49, data=20},
    {}, {}, {},    % fei
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=24},
    {}, {},        % ne
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=27},
    {}, {}, {}, {} % rung
  }% the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 50.125.
  \babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{In|ter|ak|ti|ons|ver|fei|ne|rungs|dia|gramm}%% set potentially different preferences of the hyphenation points in “Interaktionsverfeinerungsdiagramm”
  {
    {}, {},             % In
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=2},
    {}, {}, {},         % ter
    {pre=-, penalty=49, data=6},
    {}, {},             % ak
    {pre=-, penalty=50, data=9},
    {}, {},             % ti
    {pre=-, penalty=52, data=12}, %%% higher penalty because of the pronunciation t͡si̯oː
    {}, {}, {},         % ons
    {pre=-, penalty=48, data=16},
    {}, {}, {},         % ver
    {pre=-, penalty=49, data=20},
    {}, {}, {},         % fei
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=24},
    {}, {},             % ne
    {pre=-, penalty=51, data=27},
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % rungs
    {pre=-, penalty=47, data=33},
    {}, {}, {},         % dia
    {pre=-, penalty=50, data=37},
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {}  % gramm
  }%the arithmetic mean of the penalties is 49.8.
\fi
\showoutput
\begin{document}
Interaktionsdiagramme
Interaktionsverfeinerung
Interaktionsverfeinerungsdiagramm
\end{document}
```

This example is a demonstration and therefore, small as such.  In a real-world, full-blown example, we currently have 77 `\babelposthyphenation[…]{…}{…}` entries, one entry per word.  The result is great: the words get the hyphenation penalties around the standard `\hyphenpenalty` on the console output, and we specify meaningful preferences of how to break the compounds.

We made some general choices which we're unsure of:

1. We set `\exhyphenpenalty` to the minimum of all the explicitly specified penalties − 1.  The rationale is that the preferred breaking point is always after a dash inside a compound word, but there is no point of encouraging line breaks after such dashes beyond necessity.
2. The penalties per word are chosen as close to `\hyphenpenalty` (which is 50 by default) as possible on average. To measure “as close as possible on average”, we arbitrarily chose to compute the arithmetic mean (just because this computation is simple but for no other reason). The alternatives could be taking the geometric mean, the logarithmic mean, the quadratic mean, the harmonic mean, the median, or some other kind of averaging. Our goal is: for each word explicitly specified via `\babelposthyphenation`, LuaLaTeX should attempt to move the position within the word at which the word is broken rather than encourage or discourage breaking the specified word as a whole or encourage or discourage breaking the other words of the paragraph containing the specified word (when compared to the case of the absent specification and all penalties being standard `\hyphenpenalty`). Of course, we are aware that this is an imprecise and a probably ideal, unreachable goal.

Do we need to adjust these two choices in general? If so:

- why and
- how?

Of course, these choices are meant to be a guideline, a rule of thumb, which we intend to observe in general. (No doubt we might hypothetically allow ourselves to deviate from such a guideline in the future for yet unknown special, particular words, for a yet unknown reason.)

Comment: "For instance, in the above MWE, Interaktionsverfeinerungsdiagramm would get penalty 100 for the hyphenation point ver-fei. At the same time, a standalone word Verfeinerung would get penalty 49 for all the the hyphenation points given by Ver-fei-ne-rung"  that seems to be user error, you want the standard penalty for hyphenating each part of a compound, and _lower_ penalty for hyphenating at the compound join, you don't want higher penalties for hyphenating long words

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Concerning the actual penalty values: oh, I was not aware of that. I thought that in an ideal world, we'd have *lower* penalties only after the dash in compounds. I implemented this by saying `\exhyphenpenalty=48`. Now you're telling me that in an ideal world, we'd better have lower penalties also at the word borders in compounds. Hm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle After a second thought, for an average explicitly specified word (e.g., *Interaktionsverfeinerungsdiagramm* in the MWE), a user should wish to neither encourage nor discourage breaking within this word taken as a whole in comparison to the situation in which the user doesn't change the penalties. What the user wishes to do, however, is to say how to preferably break within the word in case LuaLaTeX decides to break within the word anyway. In practice, does this mean that we wish to lower the values after "penalty=" in `\babelposthyphenation[…]{…}{…}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Concerning your claim “you want the standard penalty for hyphenating each part of a compound”: I object for German. The word list https://repo.or.cz/wortliste.git/blob/HEAD:/wortliste sets priorities for different hyphenation points. Example: “Feuerwehrmannanwärter” is viewed as “(((Feu+er)+wehr)+mann)+(an+(wär+ter))”, with the weakest binding after “Feuerwehrmann” and the strongest bindings within “Feu-er” and “wär-ter”. The word “anwärter” (properly: “Anwärter”) is NOT an compound, but within this word, you prefer to break after the prefix “an” rather than within “wärter”.

Comment: well still you could reduce the penalty for `An-` rather than raise the penalties within `wärter` otherwise you are specifying what you say happens, that hyphenation should be prefered in short words with just one level of hyphenation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142180/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-albert-nash).